# Proof of divisibility using modular arithmetic: $5\mid 6^n - 5n + 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that:

$$6^n - 5n + 4 \space \text{is divisible by 5 for} \space n\ge1$$

Using Modular arithmetic. Please do not refer to other SE questions, there was one already posted but it was using **induction,**  I want to use this number theory method.

Obviously we have to take $\pmod 5$

So:

$$6^n - 5n + 4 \equiv x \pmod 5$$

All we need to do prove is prove $x = 0$

How do we do that? I just need a hint, I am not sure how to solve congruences. Some ideas will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very simple problem that has been dressed up with a red herring and many students will fall into the trap. What you need to remember is that you can add and subtract congruences of the same modulus all day as long as you mind the "wrap-around."

Comment: Check the last digit. If it is $0$ or $5$ then it is divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:-**
$6\equiv1 \pmod 5\implies 6^n\equiv1\pmod 5\tag{1}$

$-5(n-1)\equiv 0\pmod 5\tag{2}$

**Solution:-**

> $(1)+(2)$ gives,$$6^n-5n+4\equiv0\pmod 5$$

Comment: How did you devise $-5(n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ ?? How do you find the congruent residue in general?

Comment: @Amad27: It's just because $-5\equiv 0\pmod 5$.

Comment: Then multiply both sides by $(n-1)$?

Comment: @Amad27: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Great Answer =)

Answer (score 5):

Directly:
$$6^{n}-5n+4=\left(6-1\right)\left(6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}+\cdots+6^{1}+6^{0}\right)-5n+5=$$$$5\left(6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}+\cdots+6^{1}+6^{0}-n+1\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints. Working modulo $5$, we have $5 = 0$ and $6 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can go much simpler than that. Given any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $6^n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ (look up "automorphic numbers" sometime). We can ignore $5n$ because $5n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ regardless. So, working with modular arithmetic, we're essentially left with $1 + 4 = 0$.